# Bash: Divide a file based on line count and save data to two different files, how is it done?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a bash script which is supposed to run on a list of files, count the number of lines per file, then divide the number of lines by two and save the first half of the file to one file and the second half of the file to another file.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(ls .); do
count=$(wc -l $file)
half=$(($count/2 ))
head -n $half $file > $file-1h.list
tail -n $half $file > $file-2h.list
done
```

But it doesn't work... what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: For one: don't parse the output of `ls`: use `for file in *; do` instead. You'll need to check that you really have a file with `[[ -f $file ]] || continue`.

Comment: For two: `count=$(wc -l < file)`. Otherwise `count` also contains the filename.

Comment: For three, use more quotes.

Comment: For four, don't read the file twice…

Comment: How do I export the first half data to one file and second half of the data to a second file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem occurs here:

```
count=$(wc -l $file)
```

It returns the `no. of line _and_ filename`. The filename cannot be used in the `count/2` calculation, so you get an error. It should be:

```
count=$(wc -l <"$file")
```

This will only return the number of lines.

However, you will run into many more problems if you do not check the number of lines, and use another method for splitting the files. (how will you handle a file with an `odd` number of lines?

Here is an example of a bit more robust implementation. Remember **always quote your variables**

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *; do

    [ -f "$file" ] || continue          # make sure it is a file (not dir)

    count=$(wc -l <"$file")             # get total lines
    [ "$count" -lt 2 ] && {             # skip files with less than 2 lines
        printf "error file '%s' cannot be divided\n" "$file" >&2
        continue
    }
    half_1=$((count/2 ))                # divide by 2 (will round down if odd)
    half_2=$((count-half_1))            # get the other 1/2 by subtraction

    head -n $half_1 "$file" > "$file-1h.list"
    tail -n $half_2 "$file" > "$file-2h.list"

done
```

Comment: Can't you achieve the same while reading the file only once? `;)`.

Comment: You do only read the file once :) Oh, you are talking about `head/tail`. Sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split command like below:

```
split -l 500 myfile segment
```

Where -l is for number of lines
myfile is large file that you want to split
segment - is a prefix for each split.

So if i have 1000 lines in myfile, then it will create 2 files with 500 lines each like:

```
segmenta
segmentb
```

In gnu you could use -n (i.e. number of splits) as below and read file just once:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *; do
    split -n 2 ${file} ${file}.
done
```

In other case, a dirty and hacky way using split would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *; do
    split -l $[ $(wc -l ${file} | cut -d" " -f1) * 50 / 100 ] ${file} ${file}.
done
```

Here you loop over each file, and calculate count i.e. 50% of lines in file and split into two halves.

Comment: How do I export the first half data to one file and second half of the data to a second file?